# How to use UISegmented control to keep the user logged in

Tags: iphone, xcode, authentication, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm creating a simple app that loads a modal view in the root view controller, and that modal view has a segmented control for a user to choose if he/she wants to stay logged in. The modal view has a username and password field with a submit button below it. After the app verifies the user, he/she will be taken to the root view controller that has buttons to take the user to another view i.e. Feature 1, Feature 2, etc. If the user taps the back button (driven by a navigation controller), I want the user not to be asked again for his/her credentials when the app loads the root view controller again, thus the use of the segmented control.

How can use and implement the segmented control in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've realised this, but you need to store the login credentials, I assume your question is 'How!?'

If you want to store the login credentials for just the lifetime of the app (they are logged out when you close the app), I'd store the variables in Globals class so that they can be referenced from anywhere in the app.

If you want to keep the login credentials stored longer (i.e. they may still be logged in if they close and reopen the app), you should use NSUserDefaults:

Writing:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"UserIsLoggedIn"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Reading:

```
BOOL loggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"UserIsLoggedIn"];
```

Please also note the following considerations though:

- UserDefaults aren't secure. Please don't store passwords there without encrypting them.
- `boolForKey:` returns NO if the key you provide doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I'll try to see on how to implement it in my app using NSUserDefaults. :)

Comment: Storing username and password in user defaults is all nice and easy until people realize you are storing their password in clear text :)

Comment: That fine with me ficheck since this is just pure wireframes. A better security implementation will be used here when web services takes place. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are u going for UISegmentedController? Just use simple UIBarButtonItem as Logout button on RootViewControllers navigation bar.
In RootViewControllers `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` method check wheather user is already Logged in or not. Based on that loads modal view.

Comment: I wanted to implement that but client wants to use UISegmentedControl. :(

Comment: Hmmm some time simple task turns into complications because of client requirements..!

Comment: Yeah. Good thing I was able to implement it fine. ;)